# JavaScript comparison statement

Tags: javascript, comparison

can someone explain this comparison statement ?
I understand how to compare with && and || but the one liner below does something else

```
typeof(varName) === 'undefined' == 0
```

Comment: Where does that code come from? Because it's terrible. I might expect something like it from minification but it's definitely not minified.

Comment: See this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Erm, anyway `type varName === "undefined` (brackets are superfluous and unneeded) will check if `varName` is `undefined`. Then the result of _that_ is loosely checked against zero, which is the same as checking if it's `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say that `varName` is undefined. Your line of code goes through these steps (each new line is the next step):

```
typeof(varName) === 'undefined' == 0
typeof(undefined) === 'undefined' == 0
'undefined' === 'undefined' == 0
true == 0
false
```

Now lets say that `varName` is defined as equal to `5`:

```
typeof(varName) === 'undefined' == 0
typeof(5) === 'undefined' == 0
'number' === 'undefined' == 0
false == 0
true
```

This is bad code. You can get the same result with `typeof(varName) !== 'undefined'`

Comment: Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(varName) === 'undefined' == 0
```

The above expression can also be written as

```
!(typeof(varName) === 'undefined')
```

Instead of using **Not** operator (`!`) they have used `== 0`. But if you do `===0`, it will not work because it will also check for datatype and will always return `false`.

**example :**

```
true == 0  => false
false == 0 => true
```

But if you use `===`

```
true === 0  => false
false === 0 => false
```

Note: `typeof(varName) === 'undefined' == 0` is a **bad** way to do it.

Use not operator:

```
!(typeof(varName) === 'undefined')
```